# How can I get TikTok to work on vb.Net's WebBrowser?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I am trying to get the TikTok trending page (https://www.tiktok.com/en/trending) through the vb.net WebBrowser.

However when I navigate to it using WebBrowswer.  it loads for about a second then everything disappears leaving a black page.

Any idea how to resolve this so the page stays?

The WebBrowser works when we use 'https://www.tiktok.com', but not when we use 'https://www.tiktok.com/en/trending'

I thought it had something to do with the WebBrowser control by default using emulation mode of IE 7 and I changed it to the latest version on my machine.  The result turned out exactly the same.

My code is listed below.

```
Private Sub FrmTikTok_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim sUrl As String = "https://www.tiktok.com/en/trending"
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(sUrl)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Tiktok is a mobile app, even if you try on a pc you will only get a few trending vids. Use an android emulator like KOPLAYER. They just don't want you to be using the app on a pc.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening that link in any version of IE. It has the same behavior that you are describing. You are going to need to use a different Webbrowser control that isn't based on IE. [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview) might be a control that is worth looking into as it is based on Edge. There are also third party controls you can search for online.

Answer (score 0):

**How To Use TikTok On PC Without Bluestacks? (5 Methods)**

1. First of all: go to Chrome Web Store, then write TikTok on the search box, then press the enter. click on TikTok Mobile&Download and, then click on Add To Chrome.
2. click on Add extension in the box.
3. click on TikTok Mobil&Download extension.

[How To Use TikTok On PC Without Bluestacks?](https://www.typeseo.tech/2020/09/use-TikTok-on-pc-without-bluestacks.html)